# How set MongoDB case insensitive?

Tags: mongodb

I added index to my login with collation without case sensitive, but, unfortunately I wrote some wrong. I took an example from [this](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-case-insensitive/) site. This is command to create index what I wrote:

`db.users.createIndex( { login: 1 },  {collation: { locale: "en",  strength: 2 }, unique: true} );`

And this doesn't find "Text" if in db kept "text"

Does anyone know what the error is?

Comment: Ok, maybe I misunderstood and this intended only to inserting

Comment: The index does not change *behavior* of inserts or queries. You still need to query with the collation set appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

According to the law of meanness, 10 minutes after I asked, I found the answer myself. Here's how I was able to use case insensitive search:

`db.users.find({login:"lenkoras"}).collation({locale:"en",strength:2})`.
I'm sorry for this embarrassment